# Computing mean of Python numeric vector in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, porting, matlab-engine

I am trying to compute the mean of a **Python** numeric vector in MATLAB. To clarify, I am using Python but am trying to rely on some MATLAB-specific functions by running MATLAB in a Python environment. I am using `matlab.engine` to do this:

```
##### (From my Python script) #####
# Simple MATLAB experiment
import numpy as np
!pip install matlab
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

data = np.arange(5)
data_list = data.tolist()
eng.workspace['foo'] = data_list
eng.eval('mean(foo)')
```

I keep encountering the following error after the last line:

*"File /Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/toolbox/matlab/datafun/mean.m, line 127, in mean Invalid data type. First argument must be numeric or logical."*

To my understanding, this is owing to MATLAB somehow not recognizing the type of objects stored in `data_list` when `data_list` is being ported over to the engine workspace (as `foo`). I've tried (1) specifying the `dtype` when creating the object data, and (2) removing `data.tolist()` and porting `data` over directly, but both methods do not fix the issue. (Method 2 produces a different error, *"TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray"*.)

I am using MATLAB R2018b and Python 3.6.

Could anyone here help to troubleshoot? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the MATLAB engine function, the list is being converted to a cell.

> When you pass Python® data as input arguments to MATLAB® functions,
>   the MATLAB Engine for Python converts the data into equivalent MATLAB
>   data types.

As documented [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html).

You can confirm that the data type is cell in MATLAB

```
>>> eng.eval('class(foo)')
'cell'
```

Now that you know the datatype, simply convert the data:

```
>>> eng.eval('mean(cell2mat(foo))')
2.0
```